# Scroll control with JQuery / Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am looking for to mimic the same scroll behavior the new Flickr website has at https://www.flickr.com/#section-1.

No matter how hard or fast you move your mouse scroll wheel the result is the same.

I know this is a kind of parallax website but I am more interested in the scroll control.

This is what I am doing right now using this plugin https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll:

```
var mypos = $(window).scrollTop();
var up = false;
var newscroll;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    newscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
        $(window).disablescroll(); //disable scroll
        //$('body').addClass('stop-scrolling'); //a css that inputs an overflow hidden
        $('#video_bkg').stop().animate({
            height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 500);
        up = !up;
    } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
        $('#video_bkg').stop().animate({
            height: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        }, 500, function() {
            $(window).disablescroll('undo'); //reenable scroll
        });
        up = !up;
    }
    mypos = newscroll;
});
```

But none of this equals the Flickr's effect.

Comment: You should use `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` when the `mousewheel` event is fired. Then you should scroll to the next/prev section depending on mousewheel direction. And also trigger a time counter every time you scroll: this will allow you to avoid change sections too fast. I think that the only jquery plugin you need is mousewheel. I guess you can figure out the code to do that.

Comment: This is the direction I needed, thanks folk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/oevqvne2/1/) that does this using the [fullPage jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

to initialize the script.